# How can I convert a utf8 to ISO-8859-1 in Dart?

Tags: dart

I need to use iso-8859 type in flutter but the method iconv not supported, is there any other method ?

Comment: the arabic character not supported in latin1, i need to encode an arabic letters, what converter should I use?

Answer (score 5):

I'd convert it to a string and then convert the string to the ISO-8859-X code page that you want, which in this case is probably ISO-8859-6 Latin/Arabic.
The `convert` package (now) supports all the [ISO-8859 code pages](https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/convert-library.html#properties).

```dart
import "dart:convert" show utf8;
import "package:convert" show latinArabic;
...
  var utf8Bytes = ...;
  var string = utf8.decode(utf8Bytes);
  var latinArabicBytes = latinArabic.encode(string);
```

You can create helper converter for that as:

```dart
  final utf8ToLatinArabicConverter = utf8.decoder.fuse(latinArabic.encoder);
  final utf8ToLatinARabic = utf8ToLatinArabicConverter.convert;
  ....
     var latinArabicBytes = utf8ToLatinArabic(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: great, but the arabic character not supported in latin1, i need to encode an arabic letters, what converter should I use?

Comment: Nor sure which encoding is traditionally used for Arabic characters. It might be ISO-8869-6. There is no converter for that built into the Dart platform libraries.
I'd recommend keeping the characters as UTF-8 instead.
What is your use-case for converting to a different representation?

Comment: printing arabic characters on a bluetooth printer supported by the ISO CodePage from Flutter app

Comment: Have updated answer to use package:convert's new(ish) ISO-8859 code pages support.